# Paypal IPN Simulator always returns INVALID despite postback being correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

We're in the process of upgrading our IPN to use TLS and am consistently getting INVALID posted back when using the IPN Simulator

Right as the request comes in to the listener, it is logged. Right before the data goes back to paypal, the URL and the data are logged. This info is below.

There appears to be nothing wrong with the data. I've even used diffmerge to identify that there are no differences except cmd=_notify-validate&

Is it just that the [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) doesn't ever return valid?

---

The URL right before the request is:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

---

The posted data is

```
cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Mon May 23 2016 17:41:16 GMT 1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=jimmyred99@gmail.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John Smith&address_country=United States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San Jose&address_street=123 any street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=paypaltest@akturatech.com&receiver_id=paypaltest@akturatech.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=CHIMPREWRITER-LIFE&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=139&mc_gross_1=139&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=928133899&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AU-9VToMcj-IcSKMfmb8nz2kgIe.
```

---

The data from Paypal is

```
payment_type=instant&payment_date=Mon May 23 2016 17:41:16 GMT 1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=jimmyred99@gmail.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John Smith&address_country=United States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San Jose&address_street=123 any street&business=seller@paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=paypaltest@akturatech.com&receiver_id=paypaltest@akturatech.com&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=CHIMPREWRITER-LIFE&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=139&mc_gross_1=139&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=928133899&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AU-9VToMcj-IcSKMfmb8nz2kgIe.
```

---

For reference, the code is:

```
// This was legacy code I was trying in case there were formatting problems. The code "cmd=_notify-validate&" + _request.Form; does some URL encoding which I thought might be causing problems. Either way, we still get INVALID
string s = "cmd=_notify-validate";
foreach (string paramName in _request.Form)
{
    string paramValue = LicServiceTools.Encode(_request.Form[paramName]);
    //s = s + string.Format("&{0}={1}", paramName, paramValue);
    s = s + string.Format("&{0}={1}", paramName, _request.Form[paramName]);
}

string address = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
if (this.useSandBox)
{
    address = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
//Set values for the request back
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// ALSO DOESNT WORK
//string strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + _request.Form;
//req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

errorLogger.Info(s);
errorLogger.Info(address);

//Send the request to PayPal and get the response
StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(s);
streamOut.Close();
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();

// at this point, strResponse = INVALID
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the new IPN Simulator payment_date messes things up, because of the "+" in the timezone. None of the live notifications seem to list the timezone like this, so the previous code was working.

This thread saved the day: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/issues/51

Comment: Thank you for resolving this absolutely HIV positive problem for me. Wasted several hours on this until I finally found your post. Legend!!!

Comment: No worries Aaron :)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this info, James. I already spent 2 days and a lot of code changing thinking that it's my code that's broken. Thanks  again.