# PayPal MVC5 IPN listener - failing on postback to PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate PayPal IPN into my website, but it is failing consistently on the postback to PayPal. I have tested this through the Sandbox, using both the IPN simulator and through the site itself.
If run this through code via the IPN simulator, I get the “IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Please review your information” error message. If I run this via the system itself I get an http 500 error.

I have searched the internet for possible solutions for several days now, including previous posts to StackOverflow and the PayPal forums, and believe I have tried pretty much everything that I found, including:

1. The site runs under https.
2. I have verified with my hosting provider that the SSL certificate and the TLS protocol are up to snuff per the security upgrade requirements for PayPal.
3. I have the sandbox account set to use UTF-8 encoding via the sandbox profile of my test merchant account. As you can see in the code, I am asking for UTF-8 encoding in the listener.
4. I have tried this with the notify URL set with both a trailing slash and no trailing slash.
5. I have verified that the info I send back is an exact duplicate of what I have received, with only the addition of the “cmd=_notify-validate” name value pair.

The site is built in MVC5 (C#) with Visual Studio and is still in development.  The listener routine code is below.  The code fails consistently on the req.GetRequestStream command.  I know that the routine executes up to this point. But it never returns from the command.

Interestingly enough, if I point my listener code to the production PayPal environment, I can complete the round trip, with no other coding or processing changes. I get an INVALID response back - expected since the IPN did not originate in the production environment - but it at least returns.  I get no response at all if I point my listener to the sandbox environment.

Any ideas? I am at a total loss.

Listener code follows:

```
        public ActionResult IPN()
    {
        string url = "https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        //string url = "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(param);

        strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();

        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (response == "VERIFIED")
        {
             // verified processing
        }
        else if (response == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing this as well, but only with ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com. ipnpb.paypal.com works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ultimately switched to Stripe for payment processing. Much easier to incorporate and a better user experience for what I need to do. I did not try the PayPal IPN with the live PayPal site.  My site is brand new, and it's not ready to move to production mode.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. By the way, I did figure out what was wrong. PayPal are increasing the security requirements for interacting with their IPN servers. Right now, only ipnpb.sandbox needs TLS1.2, which is only supported starting OpenSSL 1.0.1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35097466/880837

Comment: At least for me, my postback wouldn't connect to sandbox because I can't make requests with TLS1.2 until I upgrade my OpenSSL and curl libraries.

Comment: Side note, do Stripe have something similar to paypal's IPN callback? They look interesting.

Comment: Stripe does have something similar to PayPal's IPN callback - Stripe calls it 'webhooks'. It is used for things such as subscription renewals, chargebacks, etc., not needed for a simple payment transaction - unlike PayPal. Side note: I did verify that I am running under TLS1.2 - the PayPal IPN process still fails.

Comment: Hi, I had this problem too for the past few days and one of the codes I was  using was exactly as the one above. I followed the recommendation from this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37806003/906815) then I got verified even when using the IPN simulator. PayPal's response is always invalid is because of the "+" in the payment_date. More details on the link I provided. HTH.